# How to use current URL to modify a HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

This is my first question on this website, but it have been helping me a lot throughout the years. I have created a custom HTML form using Google Forms entry codes to tabulate the entries into a Google Spreadsheet. Everything works perfectly, however I would like each user who fill out the form to have their own personal link. This can easily be done using the original Google Form link

[https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/{Google](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/%7BGoogle) Form code}/viewform?entry.669816638={Username}

This will autofill the username name section of the form, however, this link is in a HTML code, not in the browser. When a user fills out the form at [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/), I have a way to email them their personal link using parameters

[www.example.com/?username={The](http://www.example.com/?username=%7BThe) username they have entered in the for}

But I have no idea how to use that information to modify the form HTML code. How can I do that in the most simplest and dynamical way? Thank you

Comment: Please consider that user names might be guessed easily. Typically, one would use a hash/uuid with a limited lifetime to identify a user in this situation. But I don't know anything about the google forms.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need the parameters of the URL passed into your page and add some content using it.

```css
const queryString = window.location.search;
    
console.log(queryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
console.log(urlParams.get('username'));
```

similar idea to whats already here but this will get you exactly the string you're looking for.